# How to reset antd ProForm fields by clicking the submit button?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have used antd proForm to create a form. I have used `form.resetFields()` to reset form fields by clicking submit button but it doesn't work. how can I fix it? here is my code:

```
const onFinishHandler = async (value) => {
    try {
      await axios.post("URL", {...}})
      form.resetFields()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

```
<ProForm layout="horizontal" onFinish={onFinishHandler} form={form}>
   <ProFormSelect name="vendor" label="Vendor" width="md" options={vendorOptions} />
   <ProFormDigit name="cost" label="Cost" width="sm" />
   <ProFormDatePicker name="purchaseDate" label="Purchase Date" />
   <div className="ant-form-btn">
      <Form.Item className="ant-form--add-btn">
         <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
       </Form.Item>
    </div>
</ProForm>
```

Comment: Does `form.resetFields()` works if you try to reset fields on a normal button click event?

Comment: @NoNam4 no it doesn't work